# Problem with my Mendota Seabrook Model D-30 Direct Vent Gas Insert

Tags: gas, fireplace, pilot-light, gas-burner, thermocouple

I have a Mendota Seabrook Model D-30 Gas Fireplace that  keeps shutting off, sometimes after 1 minutes other times after 10 minutes. It has been running fine for about 9 years, but then started having problems this year.

First, it was the pilot light that gave me a hard time. The pilot flame kept shutting off, but once it was on, I was able to turn the heat on, and it stayed on.

After that, the main burner started shutting off after  few minutes of operation. I can hear the solenoid clicking when the burner flame dies.

I tried a bunch of things, like cleaning the thermocouple, the thermopile, vacuuming the silt, cleaning the head with a straw, etc...for no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has it ever been professionally serviced/inspected in 9+ years? DIY has it's limits, and fiddling with the fire in a box in your house is perhaps a place where you might want to consider hiring licensed, competent help when out of your depth. The house you don't burn down could be your own... In my area you get a yearly inspection/cleaning or you can kiss your homeowner's insurance coverage in the event of a fire goodbye.

Comment: When the main burner shuts off, does the pilot shut off also?  You need to have the pilot burning in order for the main burner to work.  My insert has a CO (carbon monoxide) detector that shuts off the pilot if a high level of CO is detected.  When the pilot shuts off, so does the main burner.  Mine does this after a hour or two of operation, unless I keep a window or two cracked to let in some fresh air.

Answer (score 0):

A non-working pilot light that doesn't remain lit could have blockage in it's line, but most likely at it's orifice where the gas pathway is narrowest.

If the main burner ignites and burns,but than shuts-off than it could be the thermo-couple needs replacing. First make sure the top 1/3rd of the thermo-couple end is positioned directly in the pilot flame otherwise it wont send the electric signal that is generated by heat to the gas valve to remain open.

I'm not sure all heaters have this saftey feature, but if your exhaust vent draw is not adequate (that is there is blockage) the heater may be sensing this and as a precaution shutting off the gas flow.

Lastly, and i find this to be a common problem, check/replace the thermostat. If it's a basic (2) wire model remove it's face to expose the wires. Should be (but not always) a Red and White. You can jump these by bridging them with a similar sized wire. The heater should ignite (make sure the pilot is working first).